# some confusion in lower limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

which of the following function is continious  from $R_{l}$ to $R_{l}$ where$R_{l}$ isthe lower limit topology   ?

1.f(x) = x

2.f(x) =[x]

3.f(x) = sinx

as option 1  is correct by definition ,,im confused about option 2 and option 3 pleas help me

Comment: If $[x]$ represents the floor the function, then it is continuous. But $\sin x$ is **not continuous**.

Comment: thanks... Pisco,,

Comment: why pisco? can u give some reason

Comment: The preimage of $[1/2,2)$ under $\sin x$ is not open in lower limit topology.